# php.ini does not exist in my apache/bin folder, but I'm getting an error?

Tags: apache, php, error-reporting, cgi-bin

I've been trying to figure out how to resolve this error with all the new pages I create:

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

localhost
2011/11/28 13:36:56
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

Well, it all started when I increased the security on MySQL by setting some more passwords, I think.  I figured I'd get a better error report if I turned error reporting on in `php.ini`, but it's not in my `/apache/bin` folder.

Alright, so I have no idea what to do.  I've also got this line in xampp: `MySQL database   DEACTIVATED`.

Any idea what might be happening?  Also, please let me know if this should go to superuser.

Comment: SUGGESTION: Make sure you can start and stop MySQL. It sounds like maybe you messed up the MySQL password. These links have some good tips: http://apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=130759     http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux, try a "find", like this:

```
find / -name php.ini print
```

Another approach is to create a "phpinfo.php" in your Apache DocumentRoot folder, and let PHP tell you where you should put your php.ini:

```
<?php
  // Create this file in your Apache root, 
  // then browse to http://localhost/phpinfo.php
  // Look for "Configuration File (php.ini) Path" in the resulting output
  phpinfo ();
 ?>
```

Comment: there's a `php.ini` in my `xampp/php` folder.

Comment: And I'm not on linux because the community is prejudice against handicappers.

Comment: ?what?  What do you mean?
Q: Now that you've found php.ini, have you enabled error checking?  
Q: Have you checked the Apache logs?  
Q: Are there any error messages you can cut/paste?

Comment: Q: What's a "handicapper"?  What "community is prejudiced against them"?  Why?

Comment: Maybe we could start another topic.  I don't want to stray too far.  So I checked and show_errors is on.  Any ideas as to how I might figure out what's goin on?

Comment: SUGGESTION: Make sure you can start and stop MySQL.  It sounds like maybe you messed up the MySQL password.  This link has some good tips:  http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=130759

Comment: I posted the answer as an extension of yours, but it was denied.  I need to repost it to present a complete solution.

Comment: So what is a "handicapper"?  And what's the deal with Linux?

Comment: Very well, I will explain.  All the common Linux platforms are lacking in text-to-speech software.  Linux supports Festival as its primary for visually impaired users, but Festival is not being developed for handicapped users.  They're a decade behind in everything but pronunciation.  Though there have been requests by collaborations of handicapped users, Festival refuses to commit its funding to development for this purpose.  And yet, Linux distros still support it.  It's a huge and terribly bitter technological walling out of the visually impaired by Linux devs and contributors.

Comment: As a natural side effect, visually impaired people are discouraged by Universities from studying Computer Science.  There are special cases, but the accepted standard at educational institutions is to tell visually impaired people that they cannot be programmers, even if it is their passion.  Naturally, visually impaired users want to fit in and find a way to right the wrong, themselves.  It's difficult to develop for a system that cannot be navigated, though, of course.  We have to develop externally.  Try putting on the blinders for a few days and get into a Linux box.  It's an embarrassment

Comment: Someone disliked my question, I think.  So, I gave it another read.  I guess I only asked where `php.ini` was.  Even though more information could and should be given, I suppose your answer is adequate.  *sigh*.  These foolish programmers have no poetry in them.  If the same problem leads others to this question, then they should likely have the same issues and be seeking the same solution.  Guides to troubleshooting 500 errors are hard to find, you know?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `find` feature in Linux, as specified by paulsm4 to find `php.ini`.

Use `ctrl+f` in Windows and search for `files and folders -> php.ini` to find it in Windows.  I recommend you do this from your web server's root directory rather than from some other location; otherwise, it may fail.

If you're experiencing a 500 error, you should check your Apache log files.  They can be found in the `/apache/logs` folder in the file `error.log`, I believe.  I emptied the file and then caused the error to isolate it.  The information lead me to the answer.

In my case, the reason I was getting a 500 error was because my `.htaccess` file was referencing a `.htpasswrd` file that did not exist.  I changed the line of code in the `.htaccess` file that was targeting the `.htpasswrd` file to target an existing `.htpasswrd` file that I wanted to use.  I could have just as soon copied a properly formatted `.htpasswrd` file or made one from scratch, though.

I've read at multiple sources that 500 errors have many causes.  So, none of these steps are guaranteed to work for you.  If they do not, I wish you luck, and I hope that you will post a reply telling me how you fixed your 500 error, too--or, a link to a resolved question about a 500 error.